# Make ID and another column into PK

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have a `Stack` which has many `StackRequiredParameter`.

The `StackRequiredParameter` is identified by its name but multiple stacks can have parameters of the same name. Therefore the PK is a composite of its name and the id of the stack which it belongs to.

```
type StackRequiredParameter struct {
    ID      string `gorm:"uniqueIndex:idx_required_id_unique_per_stack"`
    StackID uint   `gorm:"uniqueIndex:idx_required_id_unique_per_stack"`
}
```

I've tried to implement the `Stack` as shown below.

```
type Stack struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string `gorm:"unique"`
    RequiredParameters []StackRequiredParameter `gorm:"foreignKey:ID,StackID; references:ID; constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE" json:"requiredParameters,omitempty"`

}
```

But the above returns the following error

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range [1] with length 1
```

I'm pretty sure I get that error because I'm trying to match a composite key (ID, StackID) with just the ID of the stack. But please let me know if I'm not posting enough information here.

The problem is though, I'm not sure how to do it differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is both foreign key and references should contain equal columns

```golang
type Stack struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name               string                   `gorm:"unique"`
    RequiredParameters []StackRequiredParameter `gorm:"many2many:required_stack_parameters_joins; foreignKey:ID; joinForeignKey:StackID; References:Name; joinReferences:ParameterID; constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE" json:"requiredParameters,omitempty"`
}

type StackRequiredParameter struct {
    Name string `gorm:"primaryKey"`
}
```